# Backend for a social media application

Tags: ios, backend

What is the best backend service for creating a social media application? Since Parse.com is shutting down I now need to find something else, and I do not know witch backend is best for creating a social media app where users post images and videos. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JohnnyRockex How? You mean parse-server? Hosting will be sooo expensive

Comment: Use your own hosting and write your platform on top of that - big project though.

Comment: You can create back-end in PHP or ASP.NET. I would suggest PHP as hosting and deployment would be easier then .NET, This would be custom and you also need to create APIs as well.

Comment: But again - hosting would steal all my money tho :(

Comment: You can go with AWS dedicated server with Micro instance, that would be free for 1 year. check this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_IN&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=cloud_computing_b&sc_content=aws_free_e&sc_detail=aws%20free%20tier&sc_category=cloud_computing&sc_segment=85428817621&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=IN&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!85428817621!e!!g!!aws%20free%20tier&ef_id=Vk12SgAABUNTKHjj:20160407093216:s)

Comment: @VatsalK Would that be better then using ex: backendless.com, back4app.com, cloudboost.io, firebase.com ?

Comment: @RoduckNickes Well, that would be completely based on your requirements, if you are looking for custom fully manageable back-end and database then I would suggest to go with AWS and custom back-end development OR you can purchase the shared hosting as well, however there are lots of services like parse.com, but they will also charge you some amount, so at the end both will be almost same.

Comment: @VatsalK What would you suggest if I want to get something closest to parse.com? As mentioned, I am creating a social media app. It is something like Instagram/Twitter, but another twist.What would you suggest?

Comment: @RoduckNickes genuinely I am telling you I would suggest to go with custom development, but you can go with Kinvey, Firebase, Amazon AWS Mobile Hub OR Batch. As I have not much idea about these services, you can choose wisely by reading out Pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

Use digital ocean and the open source parse server. Done me a world of God. Very flexible and has built in dashboard and push notifications

Comment: No free plan? Have to pay from start?